# Verify SMS received in Twilio is from a real phone and not a spoofed POST request

Tags: twilio

I'm creating an app where a user can sign up for phone notifications. We're verifying users by sending them a text message and then having them respond "YES" or "NO" to receive text messages.

However, we're concerned that users might be able to spoof sending a message to our webhook by using a `POST` request to it with just enough data to verify them. Is there a way in Twilio to detect if an incoming request is from Twilio or not?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with more information [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security) - `X-Twilio-Signature`. There are also a few different blog posts detailing its use, for example, [How to secure Twilio webhook URLs in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-secure-twilio-webhook-urls-in-nodejs).